# USB Mouse freezes randomly for some seconds - touchpad keeps works

Tags: usb, mouse, touchpad, freeze, logitech

in the last weeks i encountered random freezes of my usb-cable-mouse:
suddenly the cursor just stops moving.

if i use the touchpad in this moment the cursor moves on - so it is only the usb-cable-mouse that is not working for ~3-10 seconds.

under dmesg i don't see anything logged regarding mouse or usb for this moments.

my system:

```
HW: ASUS ZenBook Pro Duo UX581GV
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-49-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 16 × Intel® Core™ i9-9980HK CPU @ 2.40GHz
Memory: 31,2 GiB of RAM
```

Mouse

```
usb 1-1: new low-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c069, bcdDevice=56.01
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-1: Product: USB Laser Mouse
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
input: Logitech USB Laser Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:046D:C069.0014/input/input76
hid-generic 0003:046D:C069.0014: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Laser Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
```

edit:
i closely monitored again with `dmesg --follow` -
and found a USB disconnect and directly reconnect:

```
[28255.575031] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 25
[28255.931685] usb 1-1: new low-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[28256.085600] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c069, bcdDevice=56.01
[28256.085606] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[28256.085609] usb 1-1: Product: USB Laser Mouse
[28256.085612] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[28256.092483] input: Logitech USB Laser Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:046D:C069.0019/input/input81
[28256.151790] hid-generic 0003:046D:C069.0019: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Laser Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
```

so i think it is a hardware problem - maybe a *cable break* or similar...

**if there are any other ideas how to monitor things like this in more depth to make sure its not a software problem let me know!!**

Comment: is it wireless?

Comment: its a cable mouse :-)
(sorry i did think mentioning usb is enough... ;-) )

Comment: just making sure since most wireless have USB connections and it would be an easy explanation.

Comment: yeah you are right ;-) i forgot that most of them use a usb-receiver...

Comment: Do you have another wired mouse you can test with?  Could be a loose USB connection or broken wire in cable.  Moving mouse connects again?  Had USB hub and was close to where I used mouse, kept knocking it and would lose connection.

Comment: hmpf...
added more information to question:
could be a hardware problem...

Comment: A second mouse should say which side of computer's USB port, problem lies.  Cleaning inside mouse and the surface it is used on might help also.  Changing to another USB port also if not already done.

Comment: i will look if i find a ohter mouse...
i will test the second usb-port! good idea!

Comment: ok - that was fast - other usb-port: same problem.
will try and arrange the cable in another way - if this _fixes_ it its a broken cable...

Comment: Broken cable should show itself by moving mouse tiny bit and bending cable lightly by hand, test along whole length, or use multi meter if mouse a part.